# Firefox obj.style.hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

Just trying to figure out how to do basic feature detection in FF...

```
var    obj = $( '<div style="position:relative;top:10px;"></div>' )
  , hasTop = ({}).hasOwnProperty.apply( obj[0].style, [ 'top' ] );

// chrome hasTop === true
//     FF hasTop === false
//     IE hasTop === true
```

Or, if it's easier, I'm specifically trying to detect `MozTransform` support.

Comment: For one, you can use `.call` to eliminate the array.

Comment: @pimvdb -- Yeah, I know.  Wrote that quick when I realized `obj.style.hasOwnProperty` doesn't exist in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use typeof:

```
function isSupported (propName) {
 return typeof document.body.style[propName] !== 'undefined';
}

if (isSupported('top')) {alert('got ya'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modernizer instead.....
http://www.modernizr.com/
http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/10/09/modernizr-js-feature-detection.aspx

or this I just found:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.body.style;
    // test for the presence of CSS3 transform properties
    if (s.transform !== undefined ||
        s.WebkitTransform !== undefined ||
        s.MozTransform !== undefined ||
        s.OTransform !== undefined) {
      // do stuff for TRUE
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh... you should still be able to do what you're doing, but without jQuery.

Comment: I know I can do it without jquery (just quicker to write it that way).  My point is that the concept doesn't work and I'm wondering why.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to see if style.top exists... try something silly like: `obj[0].style.top != null`

Comment: I'm trying to detect support for it, or in my specific case for `MozTransform`

Answer (score 0):

changed to:

```
!!$('<div style="-moz-transform:translateX(10px)"></div>')[0].style['MozTransform']
```

which works fine.  Willing to see better answers and still curious why my original code doesn't work.